# cx_Freeze build_exe_options (import and from settings)

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x, cx-freeze

**I couldn't figure out what is wrong with my code**
These are my header codes

```
from tkinter import *

import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst


from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import *

from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

import time
from random import randint
```

**and this is setup file's options**

```
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["selenium"], 

"excludes": [], 

"includes":["tkinter", "selenium", "selenium.webdriver.support.ui", "selenium.webdriver.common.proxy", "tkinter.scrolledtext", "time" ]}
```

**I'm very confused about converting py files to exe**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it doesnt work properly. I think something wrong or missing with includes or packages.

Comment: Please; ask a question. "It doesn't work" is not a question; its what you are seeing. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid sorry you're right.. It was late night :( the problem is when I click a button on gui (tkinter works) selenium does nothing